# AngularJS with $resource and custom formatter/parser directive not working

Tags: angularjs

Here's an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ezTUdoDKhCUGX3848VLp

HTML:

```
<p>Hello {{data | json}}!</p>

<div>
  <textarea myconverter ng-model="data"></textarea>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngResource']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {
  $scope.data = $resource('some-data.json').get({});
})
.directive('myconverter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            function fromJson(json) {
                var out = JSON.stringify(json, null, 2);
                return out;
            }

            function toJson(text) {
                return JSON.parse(text);
            }
            ngModel.$parsers.push(toJson);
            ngModel.$formatters.push(fromJson);
        }
    };
})
;
```

The simple Hello part works fine, when the AJAX call returns, it is updated with the correct data. But the textarea is never updated. If I set a breakpoint, it appears that it is given an object with no data (but I can see the $resource methods). If I change the textarea to point to a field of the "data" object, it works as expected.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with your directive. In your controller, replace the use of $resource with something using the $http service like this (obviously include $http in your controllers dependencies):

```
$scope.data = $http({
    url:'some-data.json',
    method:"GET"
  }).then(function(result) {
    $scope.data = result.data;  
  });
```

For whatever reason, when $resource assigns the result of the call to 'data' on the scope, no watches are triggered and so when $resource completes, the model for the textarea is not updated so initially $scope.data is empty and {} is shown in the text area, the $resource call  is made, and $scope.data is updated, however the textarea watch does not kick in. Using the $http service and manually assigning the result of the call to $scope.data does work and the appropriate $watch is triggered.

You can see this by adding

```
$scope.$watch('data',function() {....});
```

somewhere in your controller and when using $resource you will see the watch only called once initially. When the $resource call is complete, the $watch never gets fired.

Comment: I wish I knew more about why the update doesn't happen, but this solved my problem.

Comment: That really isn't a fix - angular provides $resource specifically for the ease of dealing with various different $http calls.  I'm running into this issue right now, and don't want to get rid of $resource because I'd have to rewrite a portion of the application simply to re-invent $resource myself.

So the question is: why can't we use $resource and a directive?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found a [fix](http://plnkr.co/edit/zXxO2vNtpXExNy214YqR?p=preview) (for the newest Angular, at least)].

As [Glav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542604/glav) correctly mentioned, the `ngModel` watchers aren't triggerd. This is, [because Angular's modelWatch is just checking for object identity](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L2231). To prevent this, I copied (and slightly modified) the source that came afterwards. Now we have a new `directive` that we can plug to `ngModels` that have a `$resource`. I'll probably update this, to have a configurable "pending" message/directive (and the proper `priority` setting), later.

```
app.directive('isResourceModel', function() {
  return {
  restrict: 'A',
  require: 'ngModel',

  link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$formatters.push(function resourceFormatter(value){
              if (value.$promise != null && value.$resolved === false){
                value.$promise.then(function (data){
                  var viewValue = data, 
                    idx = ctrl.$formatters.length,
                    runFormatter = false;

                  while(idx--){
                    formatter = ctrl.$formatters[idx];
                    if (runFormatter
                        || (runFormatter = formatter === resourceFormatter))
                        viewValue = formatter(viewValue)
                  }
                  ctrl.$viewValue = viewValue;
                  ctrl.$render();
                  if (ctrl.$validators.length > 0)
                    ctrl.$validate();
                  });  
              }
              return value;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Edit: I made a [module](https://github.com/P-Seebauer/ng-isFutureModel) out of the answer. you can use it with `bower` like this:

```
bower install https://github.com/P-Seebauer/ng-isFutureModel.git
```